# How to handle tcp connections with clusters in nodejs

Tags: node.js, tcp, node-cluster

I am trying to understand how to handle tcp connection with cluster in nodejs. How does the master know to which child the connection should be routed. Do we need to handle this case or does node handles by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node handles it internally.

Currently the default algorithm is round robin on all non-Windows platforms. The other method merely consists of just passing the socket to the OS for it to choose which child process to send it to. This is described in the [`cluster` documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works).

Comment: do we have or else node takes care of it ? If we have to how can we get sockets fd id. ?

Comment: so once the connection is handed to one worker, that worker will handle the total tcp session ?

Comment: node automatically takes care of the passing of sockets. As I mentioned you may be able to configure the algorithm used, but you don't handle the sockets explicitly. Once a child process is given a socket, it's all theirs.